# Array chunking based on same items

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, chunks

I want to slice an array according to same elements which leads to a 2d (chunked) array. So for example:
`let arr = [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30]`,
I want the following new resulting 2d array; `[ [10, 10, 10, 10], [20, 20, 20], [30] ]` or let arr be `[2, 5, 13, 13, 15, 16, 16, 16]` which results in `[ [2], [5], [13, 13], [15], [16, 16, 16] ]`.

I made an effort like for example:

```
let a = [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30];
let b = [];
for(let i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
  if(a[i] !== a[i+1]) {
  let chunk = a.slice(a.indexOf(a[i]), a.indexOf(a[i + 1]));
    b.push(chunk);
  }
}
```

console.log(b) outputs [ [10, 10, 10, 10], [20, 20, 20], [] ]. How can I include 30 in the last (empty) array?

Comment: is the array always in sorted order?

Comment: @Bogaart, I think in for-loop last iteration (i == a.length). When using `a.indexOf(a[i + 1])`, the value of a[i+1] will be undefined right? and index will be -1. If you fix this, it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming all same values are grouped together.

You could take the last index as value for the index.

```js
let a = [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30],
    b = [],
    i = 0;

while (i < a.length) b.push(a.slice(i, i = a.lastIndexOf(a[i]) + 1));

console.log(b);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @DBS, no, sorting is not required. it is sufficient if all same values are grouped together.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30];
let obj = {};
arr.map(e => {
    obj[e] = obj[e] || [];
    obj[e].push(e);
});
let B = Object.values(obj);
console.log(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

groupt them with an object

```js
arr=[10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30]
 g={}
 res=[]
 arr.forEach(n => {
   if(!g[n]) res.push(g[n]=[])
   g[n].push(n)
 });
 console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group your values into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which keeps a frequency of each number (ie: 10 appears 4 times), where the key is the number and the value is the frequency. You can build this map using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). You can then convert the Map to an array by using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and providing a mapping function to convert the key-value pairs into chunked arrays:

```js
let a = [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30];

const res = Array.from(
  a.reduce((m, n) => m.set(n, (m.get(n) || 0) + 1), new Map),
  ([n, t]) => Array(t).fill(n)
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with `slice` call, 2nd param is -1 in last iteration of for-loop.

Just change to `a.indexOf(a[i + 1]) > -1 ? a.indexOf(a[i + 1]) : a.indexOf(a[i]) + 1`

```js
let a = [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30];
let b = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] !== a[i + 1]) {
    let chunk = a.slice(
      a.indexOf(a[i]),
      a.indexOf(a[i + 1]) > -1 ? a.indexOf(a[i + 1]) : a.indexOf(a[i]) + 1
    );
    b.push(chunk);
  }
}

console.log(b);
```

Using `for-loop` and `slice`

```js
const split = (arr) => {
  const output = [];
  let last = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== arr[i - 1]) {
      output.push(arr.slice(last, i));
      last = i;
    }
  }
  return output;
};

const arr = [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30];

console.log(split(arr));
```

Using `reduce` and `map`

```js
const split = (arr) =>
  Object.entries(
    arr.reduce((acc, cur) => ((acc[cur] = (acc[cur] ?? 0) + 1), acc), {})
  ).map(([num, count]) => new Array(count).fill(num));

const arr = [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30];

console.log(split(arr));
```